# How to debug webpacked TypeScript in VS 2017

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I am using webpack with ts-loader to transpile and bundle various TypeScript files. Here are my configs:

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [ "dom", "es2015", "es2016" ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: { 
        app: './app'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js','.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['ts-loader'],
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

My folders are organized as

```
/src
/dist
```

In the src folder I have my .ts files and the pre-webpack js and .map files that the typescript compiler creates (via ts-loader). In the dist folder I get the webpacked js with inline source maps.  The webpacked js is referenced by my html pages. When I run the project in VS and set a breakpoint in the original .ts file, the breakpoint says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."  And of course it is not hit.  How can I make the source maps work to be able to debug in my original TypeScript?

UPDATE: TypeScript debugging in VS works fine using IE or Chrome when webpack is not in the mix.  It is the addition of webpack that is causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using the angular cli: run `ng serve` open browser at localhost:4200 and inspect page. Find webpack/src/fileyouwanttodebug, place break point and refresh page

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using angular at all. Also I am wanting to debug TypeScript in Visual Studio, not JavaScript in the browser.  TypeScript debugging in VS works fine using IE or Chrome when webpack is not in the mix.  It is the addition of webpack that is causing the problem. Updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Ok my bad, just so you are aware though you can debug actual Typescript in the browser through the webpack. VS uses a launch.json file for debug scenarios, you could take a look at that. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: Thanks again. The link applies to VS Code, but I am using full VS 2017.  Do you have any info about that?

Comment: Ok, heres my final stab-- From the command-line, we now fully support the use of the –sourcemap flag, which outputs a source map file corresponding to the JavaScript output.  This file will allow directly debugging the original TypeScript source in source map-enabled browsers and Visual Studio. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2012/11/15/announcing-typescript-0-8-1/